# Topology: If $B\subset A$ and $f:A\to X$ is continuous, is $f|_{B}$ also continuous ?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(A,\mathcal T_A)$ and $(B,\mathcal T_B)$ two topological space such that $B\subset A$ and $\mathcal T_B=\{B\cap U\mid U\in\mathcal T_A\}$. To me, if $f:A\to X$ is continuous refer to $\mathcal T_A$, then $f|_B$ is also continuous refer to $\mathcal T_B$, but me teacher told me that it's wrong. Do you have an exemple ?

Comment: You are right. $f\lvert_B = f\circ \iota_B$, where $\iota_B \colon B \hookrightarrow A$ is the inclusion. $\iota_B$ is continuous.

Comment: What need not be the case, however, is that if $f\lvert_B$ is continuous and $b\in B$, then $f$ is continuous at $b$.

Comment: I don't totally understand. Is it always true that If $X_{n+1}\subset X_n$, then for all $n\in \mathbb N$ and all seminorm continuous $p:X_{n+1}\to \mathbb R$ then $p|_{X_n}$ is also continuous (refer to $\mathcal T(X_n)$). To me it seems to be always true...

Comment: Something doesn't work out there, you have $X_{n+1}\subset X_n$, yet you write $p\lvert_{X_n}$ when $p$ is defined only on $X_{n+1}$. What is true is that the restriction of a continuous map to a (topological) subspace is continuous. What is not in general true is that a function whose restriction to a subspace is continuous is itself continuous at the points of the subspace. Trivial examples are restrictions to discrete subspaces.

Comment: Yes it's $X_n\subset X_{n+1}$ and not what I wrote. Last question: if $\mathcal T_B$ is not the induced topology, the result is still true ?

Comment: The subspace topology is characterised as the coarsest topology on $B$ such that the inclusion is continuous. So for any finer topology, the restriction of continuous functions is continuous. For topologies that are coarser than the subspace topology or incomparable to it, a restriction may be continuous [e.g. if $f$ is constant] or not.

Answer (score 2):

It is true. $f$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for all open $U \subseteq X$. Now the result immediately follows from the definitoin of $\mathcal T_B$.